# makemigrations can't detect change in django

Tags: python, django, database, migration

I know there are a lot of similar questions: but I will describe my problem as simply as I can.

This is the app I want to migrate.
[image]

This is my setting.py
[image]

This is what happens when I type in makemigrations(after I add a field in my model)
[image]

This is what happens when I type in showmigrations(after I add a field in my model)
[image]

I have reinstall django using pip, I have created new app , I have created new project,new venv, I even have reinstall python itself, all same story.
I suspect my django source code has been corrupted, but when I install django using pip, it use file that is downloaded before instead of download new file. Trust me, I have tried all the way a newbie could possibly tried, could someone tell me how to redownload django itself or someone who is way smarter than me know what's going on right now.
Thx!

Comment: try with app name. python manage.py makemigrations app_name

Comment: If specifying the app name doesn't work, can you show the contents of `app/models.py`?

Comment: You are my saver !
@Iain Shelvington

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thx all your support guys! After all the struggle of finding answers on the Internet, I finally made it!!! It is due to the changes in the model, I do make a new class but

***> I forgot to inherint from the model.Model***
This is really helarious and stupid, I have to say.But this make django not able to see my class as a model, which leads to not be able to detect the change. I have to say this is really a newbie exclusive problem.

Answer (score 2):

You should try

```
python manage.py migrate
python manage.py makemigrations app
```

Apart from that, if your application works as it should, it shouldn't worry you if Django finds no migrations to apply.